# 403.60 - Forbidden error authenticating Cordova with Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: cordova, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

*Solution*
[Phonegap oauth2 redirect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564662/phonegap-oauth2-redirect-issue)
Authentication works on device but not Ripple
Still trying to figure out how to get it to work on Ripple

*Initial Problem*
I'm following the tutorials to create a starter Cordova app with authentication against an Azure App Service:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users/
and
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication/

I can browse directly to the app service at zumotest4.azurewebsites.net but the Cordova app (generated by Azure Mobile App quickstart) is failing. The azure mobile service call, `client.login('microsoftaccount');` does launch the OAuth login page but, after submitting credentials, the OAuth login screen stays open with a blank screen.  The network trace shows a 403 forbidden failure for the callback. The Azure App Service error log reports the error as HTTP Error 403.60 - Forbidden.

Backend = .NET (C#)

The server is set to 'Allow request (no action)' when a request is not authenticated.  The todo controller is set to [Authorize].

```
    [Authorize]
    public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
    {...
```

Microsoft Registered Application Configuration:

-Mobile or desktop client app: Yes

-Target domain: blank

-Restrict JWT issuing: Yes

-Root domain: zumotest4.azurewebsites.net

-Redirect URLs:

```
*https://zumotest4.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback

*https://zumotest4.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount

*https://zumotest4.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done 

*https://zumotest4.azurewebsites.net
```

Cordova client CSP:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://login.windows.net https://login.live.com https://zumotest4.azurewebsite...; style-src 'self'">`

Cordova client index.js:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://zumotest4.azurewebsites.net');

    // Login to the service
    client.login('microsoftaccount')
        .then(function () {
            // BEGINNING OF ORIGINAL CODE

            // Create a table reference
            todoItemTable = client.getTable('todoitem');

            // Refresh the todoItems
            refreshDisplay();

            // Wire up the UI Event Handler for the Add Item
            $('#add-item').submit(addItemHandler);
            $('#refresh').on('click', refreshDisplay);

            // END OF ORIGINAL CODE

        }, handleError);
}
```

Network trace:

Name: `https://zumotest4.azurewebsite..."%"3dc28004776f304afca14c71b77d660d8d_20160311125405"%"26redir"%"3d" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: https://login.live.com/oauth20..."%"3A"%"2F"%"2Fzumotest4.azurewebsites.net"%"2F.auth"%"2Flogin"%"2Fmicrosoftaccount"%"2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=wl.basic&state=nonce"%"3Dc28004776f304afca14c71b77d660d8d_20160311125405"%"26redir"%"3D" -H "Cookie: CompletionOrigin=http://localhost:4400; CompletionType=postMessage; Nonce=JpK4rfK4vvSKl3Mr6xhuJdy5b0xzu2nls5zL4ShiBrxVjw64e9n9/JXXhLlOeq3S8Pn9YFfV9G2RGowbFB4YZem5vCGwDWHV3vHoa0iT3/XvHHA9SAOD5AjlXxN3ffbk; AppServiceSessionMode=token; ARRAffinity=45469bcdd9e2de45e5ee43c5a6d02e5e7b574ac8ea3eb9b10e5cce208e5268b6" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" --compressed`

Status: 403 - Forbidden

Type: document

Initiator: `https://zumotest4.azurewebsite..."%"3dc28004776f304afca14c71b77d660d8d_20160311125405"%"26redir"%"3d" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Referer: https://login.live.com/oauth20..."%"3A"%"2F"%"2Fzumotest4.azurewebsites.net"%"2F.auth"%"2Flogin"%"2Fmicrosoftaccount"%"2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=wl.basic&state=nonce"%"3Dc28004776f304afca14c71b77d660d8d_20160311125405"%"26redir"%"3D" -H "Cookie: CompletionOrigin=http://localhost:4400; CompletionType=postMessage; Nonce=JpK4rfK4vvSKl3Mr6xhuJdy5b0xzu2nls5zL4ShiBrxVjw64e9n9/JXXhLlOeq3S8Pn9YFfV9G2RGowbFB4YZem5vCGwDWHV3vHoa0iT3/XvHHA9SAOD5AjlXxN3ffbk; AppServiceSessionMode=token; ARRAffinity=45469bcdd9e2de45e5ee43c5a6d02e5e7b574ac8ea3eb9b10e5cce208e5268b6" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" --compressed`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For reference, can you please let us know:  1) Are there any error messages in the console if you run the cordova app in a debug / ripple environment and 2) what version of the cordova-ms-azure-mobile-apps are you running?

Comment: Please note, I added a 'solution' to the original issue.  The problem is Ripple.  Authentication works in emulator.  I am using version="2.0.0-beta4" of cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps which is automatically included by the Azure quickstart.  Would be nice if authentication would work in Ripple which is convenient for its speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few additional steps needed to get authentication working in browser. Refer the resolution mentioned in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/81. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Those updates worked for me to get Ripple working.  Thanks much guys!